# Cout Doubles in Descending Order C++

Tags: c++, sorting, double

I need help. I'm writing this program that needs to calculate the differences between two ints in a .csv file. Finding the difference is easy, but as I cout the list of differences, they are in no particular order. I want to pick out the highest value of differences and cout specifically that. How would I go about doing that?

```
double diff;
  int astate;

  string line8;
   ifstream myfile8 ("elect12.csv");
    //cout << endl << "Total Popular Votes for Other Candidates: ";
     while (getline (myfile8, line))
     {
      istringstream iss(line);
      int a, b, c, d, e;
      if (!(iss >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e )) //{ break; }
       diff = (a-b);
       diff = diff/d;
       diff = diff*100;
       astate = diff;         
       /*cout << "Obama's best state was " << line8 << ", where he won by " << diff << " points." << endl;*/
       cout << astate << endl;
```

The difference is converted into a percentage. Right now, all of the differences between a & b are being returned. How do I return only the greatest difference?

I'm sorry if this makes no sense.

Comment: cout inside the loop is guilty

Comment: You have to save the largest seen difference yoursef

Comment: And ouside the loop, display it

Comment: What do you think the `if` is doing? You have commented out the `//{break;}`. Your current code means `if (!(iss >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e )){diff=(a-b);}`. Are you sure that's what you want? You should put in explicit `{` immediately after the `if(...)` in order to clarify exactly what code is conditional

Comment: Your title says "doubles in descending order".  Your question says "only the greatest".  Which is it?  Joachim Pilborg has given the answer for "greatest".  For "descending order", store in a vector, sort it, and output it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the current difference with the previous largest difference (stored in the *initialized* variable `astate`), if it's larger than the previous largest then assign. Print the value of `astate` after the loop.

Comment: @DominickAlcantara Something like that, but maybe `diff > astate` instead.

Comment: would that mean using 
    if (astate > diff) ?